# JQuery Datatables Sorting image position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables and wanted to move the sorting image say the sorting arrow image should be 10px to the right of the column headers. By changing the below css property to either left or right or center doesnt seem to work for me. i want the image(Sort image) to be 10px to the right of the cloumn header name .Say column header to be Account Manager Name.

```
.sorting_asc { 
 background: url('images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center center;    
   color:#000000;  
text-align:left;       
 }
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe adding a jsfiddle to show your example will help to describe the question clearly

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to set the parent div to relative or absolute. Then set the div that is the icon to absolute also. You can then use left and top to position your icon within this element.

Positioning can be confusing. I like this video which really does a great job at simply explaining positioning and how they interact with each other.

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/110-quick-overview-of-css-position-values/

Answer (score 0):

```js
**//You can use the following workaround to achieve the same**

 $('tableId').Datatable({
 
 initComplete: function (settings, json) {

                var spanSorting = '<span class="arrow-hack">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';
                 
                $('tableId' + " thead th").each(function (i, th) {

                    var cls = $(th).attr('class');

//only sortable column should be updaed with the new sortable span with respective background icon

                    if (cls == 'sorting' || cls == 'sorting_asc' || cls == 'sorting_desc') {
                        $(th).html($(th).html() + spanSorting);
                    }
                });
            },
 
 });
```

```css
// remove background-image for th in datatable css
 table.dataTable thead .sorting {
        background-image: none;
    }

    table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
        background-image: none;
    }

    table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
        background-image: none;
    }
    
 //Add new css property to show sorting image for dynamically created span   
table.dataTable thead .sorting span.arrow-hack {
    background-image: url("../datatables/images/sort_both.png");
    background-position: 13px 17px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc span.arrow-hack {
    background-image: url("../datatables/images/sort_asc.png");
    background-position: 13px 17px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc span.arrow-hack {
    background-image: url("../datatables/images/sort_desc.png");
    background-position: 13px 17px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```